# Code to delete a nested TabPage isn't always working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I wanted to implement a MiddleClick-To-Delete functionality, like most tabbed environments have, on my application which looks like this:

[image]

It's just a single form with a `TabControl` that has 2x `TabPage`: ActiveItems and Archived Items.

Both of those pages contain their own `TabControl`, which the user can add as many `TabPage` objects as they desire.

If the user has Active Items selected and they delete a tab, it deletes the correct one. If they delete a tab from Archived Items, it also deletes the correct one. If they move a tab from Active to Archived then delete it, it is removing the wrong tab. So in the screenshot above, you can't see Archived Items but there are 2 tabs there already. If I move 13571 from Active -> Archive, then delete it (tab #3, index #2), it removes tab #2, index #1.

```
// Both the tcActive and tcArchived, the TabControls on tcRoot's two Active Items
// and Archived Items tab pages, subscribe to this event
private void tc_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        tabPageClicked = e.Location;

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
        DeleteTab();
}

// Passes the TabControl and TabPageIndex to be deleted
private void DeleteTab()
{
    int tpi = GetTabIndex(tabPageClicked);

    if (tcActiveArchive.SelectedIndex.Equals(0))
        DeleteTab(tcActive, tpi);
    else
        DeleteTab(tcArchived, tpi);
}

// Gets the TabPage index from either Active Items page or Archived Items page
private int GetTabIndex(Point p)
{
    if (tcActiveArchive.SelectedIndex.Equals(0))
        return tcActive.TabPages.IndexOf(tcActive.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>().Where((t, i) => tcActive.GetTabRect(i).Contains(p)).First());
    else
        return tcArchived.TabPages.IndexOf(tcArchived.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>().Where((t, i) => tcArchived.GetTabRect(i).Contains(p)).First());
}

// Actual removal of TabPage at index tabIndex from TabControl tc
private void DeleteTab(TabControl tc, int tabIndex)
{
    lastDeleteWasActiveTab = (tcActiveArchive.SelectedIndex.Equals(0));

    //Tab object just stores a string, string[] and bool
    Tab deletedTab = new Tab(tc.TabPages[tabIndex].Text, ((TextBox)tc.TabPages[tabIndex].Controls[0]).Lines, lastDeleteWasActiveTab);

    if (lastDeleteWasActiveTab)
    {
        deletedActiveTabs.Push(deletedTab);
        filesToDelete.Add(mantisDir + tc.TabPages[tabIndex].Text + ".txt");
    }
    else
    {
        deletedArchiveTabs.Push(deletedTab);
        filesToDelete.Add(archiveDir + tc.TabPages[tabIndex].Text + ".txt");
    }

    tc.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabIndex);

    //Try to select the tab to the right of the one that was deleted
    if (tc.TabPages.Count >= tabIndex + 1) 
        tc.SelectedIndex = tabIndex;
    else
        tc.SelectedIndex = tabIndex - 1;

    undoQueue.Push((lastDeleteWasActiveTab) ? UndoEventType.DeleteActive : UndoEventType.DeleteArchive);
}
```

Stepping through the code for the condition described above:

- `MouseDown` event fires
- `DeleteTab()`
- `GetTabIndex` returns 2
- `DeleteTab(tcArchived, 2);` is called
- `Tab deletedTab` has all the values it's supposed to contain, indicating we're looking at the right TabPage / index.
- `tc.RemoveAt(2)` is called

Yet it deletes the second item, not the index 2. Absolutely cannot figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing this line:

```
DeleteTab(TabControl tc, int tabIndex)
{
    //other code
    tc.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabIndex);
}
```

To:

```
TabPage tp = tc.TabPages[tabIndex];
tc.TabPages.Remove(tp);
```

Seems like it works for the use case described in my original post, with minimal testing. But I'd *really* like to know why `RemoveAt(tabIndex)` isn't working.